# Printing a portion of a union/struct in a lexical analyzer

Tags: c, struct, malloc, lex

I am using lex for an independent study in compilers. For some reason I cannot get the string identifier to print. The lexemes print for all the other tokens with the exception of IDENTIFIER. I think it might be me malloc in my .lex file. I am hoping someone find my mistake. I have included the relevant code, so without further delay:

Malloc in scanner.lex:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*            {yylval.string_value.line_number = current_line_number;
                                 yylval.string_value.value = malloc(sizeof(char) *(strlen(yytext)+1));
                                 return IDENTIFIER;}
```

Union/Struct in token.h:

```
typedef union {
 struct {
      char * value;
      int line_number;
 } string_value;
 struct {
      int value;
      int line_number;
 } integer_value;
 struct {
      double value_1;
      int line_number;
 } real_value;
 int line_number;
} YYSTYPE;

YYSTYPE yylval;
```

Relevant print statement in main.c:

```
 case IDENTIFIER:
                printf("Token: %s    Line Number: %d    Lexeme: %c    Token Number: %d\n", tokenName(token),
                yylval.string_value.line_number,
                yylval.string_value.value, token);
 break;
```

What I have tried is using

```
%s
```

instead of

```
%c
```

for the formatting of printf and of course that changed nothing. I do reference the token.h file in both the .lex file and main.c. I think it might be my use of malloc although I do not get any compilation errors. I would appreciate any help and thanks.

Comment: Usually with a union type, you put the common members first, so they overlay nicely. But your union will have the `line_number` member at several different offsets. Not sure if this is relevant, but it looks weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scanner action for an identifier, you do:

```
yylval.string_value.line_number = current_line_number;
yylval.string_value.value = malloc(sizeof(char) *(strlen(yytext)+1));
return IDENTIFIER;
```

None of that actually inserts the value of `yytext` into `yylval`.

Personally, I'd do this:

```
yylval.string_value.line_number = current_line_number;
yylval.string_value.value = strdup(yytext);
return IDENTIFIER;
```

`strdup` isn't part of the standard C library, but it's in Posix and it's generally available and quite convenient. Otherwise, you could take advantage of the fact that `yyleng` is already set to the length of the token:

```
yylval.string_value.line_number = current_line_number;
char* id = malloc(yyleng + 1);
strncpy(id, yytext, yyleng);
yylval.string_value.value = id;
return IDENTIFIER;
```

In either case, don't forget that you need to `free()` the copied identifier.

---

By the way, you might want to consider using flex's builtin `yylineno` feature to count lines.

Comment: Thanks! You have been arrowed up.